# Copy string in several Excel Cells

Tags: c#, excel

I have problem with Excel, it is not to complex, but I hang here:

So, what I want to do is this:

I have a formular with a column, in this column stand a dynamic created string. For example this:

```
string example = "[CopyInCellA1][CopyInCellA2][CopyInCellA3]";
```

And I want to copy this value to put this in excel, like I have written in the[...]
As separator I have use a `','` and a `'\t'`, but they copy still the data in one cell.

Some good ideas.

Comment: Please show the code for what you are trying/have tried to do.

Comment: this is just my "code", the user must copy the string out of the formular

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you want to have 3 sections of the string copied to 3 columns (A1, A2, A3)?

Comment: yes, you have understand my goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the "Text to Columns" command on the data ribbon and easier to use a "," as separator.

HOwever this wont work off a formula, it has to be real text.  Can the user do a Copy and Paste Special - Values first?

Then the Text to Columns command will work. It will split the data according to the separator that you specify.

Wing

Comment: i have excel 2010, is there the "Text to Columns" command avaible

Comment: Yes, look at the `Data` bit of the ribbon - it's in the `Data Tools` section.